# What is the difference between ML architecture and ML model

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, model

What is the difference between ML architecture and ML model? few papers using "model" and others using "Architecture"

Is it correct if I said, "Architecture is a model that can be visualized. Models are more general"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(previous comment as answer)

As far as I understand:

In the context of neural networks the **architecture** is the number of layers, the number of nodes per layer and activation function.

The **model** itself is what is learned --> the weight values.

I think that - with creativity - anything can be visualized. Therefore, I would not differ concepts by the ability to visualize them.